# Replace a href tag by a shortcode structure with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, href, bbcode

I'm trying to replace a href and I have the following code : `<a href="http://www.mysite.com" target="_blank">My site</a>`

with that :

```
$textarea_content = '<a href="http://www.mysite.com" target="_blank">My site</a>';
$patterns = array(
    "/<a href=/",
    "/target*\=*\'*\_blank*\'*\>/",
    "/<*\/a>/"
);
$replacements = array(
    "[url=",
    "]",
    "[/url]"
);
$textarea_content = preg_replace($patterns,$replacements, $textarea_content);
```

I need to convert the link tag to this structure :

```
[url='http://www.mysite.com']My site[/url]
```

The problem is that the output is something like : `<a href="" http:="" www.mysite.com''="" target="_blank">My site</a>`

What I'm doing wrong ? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/(?:\<a\s+.*href=\"([^\"]*)"[^\>]*\>([^\<]*)\<\/a\>)/', '[url=\'\\1\']\\2[/url]', $text);
```

Assuming:

```
$text = 'Bla bla bla <a href="http://www.mysite.com" target="_blank">My site</a> bla bla bla';
```

Result:

```
Bla bla bla [url='http://www.mysite.com']My site[/url] bla bla bla
```

**EDIT** According to OP's comment below:

If want to get back your HTML you just have to do this:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?:\[url=\'([^\']*)\'\]([^\[]*)\[\/url\])/', '<a href="\\1" target="_blank">\\2</a>', $parsed);
```

Assuming:

```
$parsed = 'Bla bla bla [url=\'http://www.mysite.com\']My site[/url] bla bla bla';
```

Result:

```
Bla bla bla <a href="http://www.mysite.com" target="_blank">My site</a> bla bla bla
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! It work like a charm, but just another little question : If I want to now reverse back [url='...' target=_"blank"]...[/url] to the <a href="http://www.mysite.com" target="_blank">My site</a>